# How to handle javascript error in phantomjs selenium with java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

**I have tried a lot but I didn't get any solution how can I handle page.onError , code is as follow -**

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

I am getting following error -

> [ERROR - 2017-08-09T06:00:16.732Z] Session
>   [db2e4bf0-7cc7-11e7-a9b1-81e10abf02db] - page.onError - msg:
>   TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]')
>
> phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error [ERROR -
>   2017-08-09T06:00:16.733Z] Session
>   [db2e4bf0-7cc7-11e7-a9b1-81e10abf02db] - page.onError - stack:

Comment: The error `Session [db2e4bf0-7cc7-11e7-a9b1-81e10abf02db] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]')` says it all PhantomJS seems unable to initiate a session.

Comment: When does the error happen and what you want to exactly? You code seems different from what is raising the exception

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am crawling some sites but after some time I am getting this error

Comment: Looking at the error it seems either `document.getElementById("img")` becomes null or `images` object is nulll. This can be caused due to different thing, page load error, different html on the page. scraping protection changing the page

Comment: @TarunLalwani how to handle page load error in selenium java, I want if there is some error in javascript it should scape it and go ahead, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To work with `Selenium 3.4.0` with `PhantomJS 2.1.1` you need to provide the **absolute path** of `PhantomJS binary` through `System.setProperty` command as follows:

```
File src = new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
System.out.println("Facebook Page Loaded");
```

Comment: Let me try with it.